# Synching Two ArcMap JavaScript webmaps to respond to panning

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I am looking for some advice on how to approach a problem I am having. I am looking to build an ArcGIS webmap using JavaScript and HTML 5 that reacts to a user panning on two separate, synchronous maps.

[Modest Maps](http://modestmaps.com/) provides an excellent example of [Loading Two Maps and Synching Their Panning](http://modestmaps.com/examples/two-maps.html) that helps visualize what I need to do. However, I need to accomplish the *Loading Two Maps and Synching Their Panning* with ArcMap products.

The [Overview dijit](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/widget_overviewmap.html) in Arcmap seems to be capturing the essence of what I am trying accomplishing. However, the overview dijit  in the [widget overviewmap](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/samples/widget_overviewmap/) seems to react rather then pan synchronously.

The [dijit css](http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css) feeds into this map and can be used as a resource if needed. I couldn't find anything in it that would accomplish synchronous panning.

I am open to any ArcGIS suite methodology to accomplish the same as the Modest Maps look and feel.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
esriConfig.defaults.map.panDuration = 0;

dojo.connect(map1, "onPan", onPan);
function onPan(extent, delta) {
   map2.setExtent(extent);
}
```

This will add an event onPan of the first map and update the second map to the same extent.